# Erro ao requisitar paginas internas do CakePHP?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

Estou com um problema no meu `CakePHP`, sou completamente novato com este `framework` e o meu `erro` é o seguinte:

> `2017-05-01 10:09:45 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class PagesController could not be found.
>       Exception Attributes: array (
>         'class' => 'PagesController',
>         'plugin' => NULL,
>       )
>       Request URL: /brasil/
>       Stack Trace:
>       #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\brasil\app\webroot\index.php(227): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
>       #1 {main}`

Nas minhas pesquisas eu encontrei muita coisa falando de configurar o `mod_rewrite` e até ai já fiz de tudo pra poder liberar esta função no apache.

Agora fica a pergunta o que pode ser isso e se alguém pode me ajudar?

Vale lembrar que todos os controladores existem, foi feito um `CTRL+C` e `CTRL+V` de uma hospedagem pra outra, e na hospedagem antiga tudo estava funcionando, cheguei a conclusão de que possa ser configuração de servidor mesmo.

Comment: Por favor não esqueça de mencionar a versão exata do CakePHP (última linha em vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt ou lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: A versão que tenho aqui é a 2.6.2.